# Navigation Using Router Package in Meteor

Tags: meteor, router

I need to know about the usage of Router Package navigation in Meteor. When i need this navigation as mentioned below :

I did a sample application.In this application contains user login.When ever the user login  it will come success to go another page i.e "main" Here main is template name.

Code :

```js
Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    alert(err.reason);
  } else {
    console.log(" Login Success ");
    //Here go another Page i.e Main(main is template name) using router Package
    Router.go('main');//using this method for navigation but it cames error as shown below
  }
});
```

Router code :

```
Meteor.Router.add({
  '/':'main',
})
```

Error :

```
[14:27:51.895] "Exception in delivering result of invoking 'login': ["submit #login-form"]/<@http://localhost:3000/client/views/login.js?c31d1b51f33bf5de460100e196ef33eb38475f65:24
_.once/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:801
Accounts.callLoginMethod/loggedInAndDataReadyCallback@http://localhost:3000/packages/accounts-base.js?7b90b1939a52b5c6ad91265df4dd167bd5f4ebdb:467
Meteor.bindEnvironment/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?148e9381d225ecad703f4b858769b636ff7a2537:822
._maybeInvokeCallback@http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?502d55e7a7449f770e46330161cb7bd525c4417a:3782
.receiveResult@http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?502d55e7a7449f770e46330161cb7bd525c4417a:3802
._livedata_result@http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?502d55e7a7449f770e46330161cb7bd525c4417a:4805
Connection/onMessage@http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?502d55e7a7449f770e46330161cb7bd525c4417a:3647
._launchConnection/self.socket.onmessage/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?502d55e7a7449f770e46330161cb7bd525c4417a:2709
_.forEach@http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:156
._launchConnection/self.socket.onmessage@http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?502d55e7a7449f770e46330161cb7bd525c4417a:2708
SockJS</REventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent@http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?502d55e7a7449f770e46330161cb7bd525c4417a:150
SockJS</SockJS.prototype._dispatchMessage@http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?502d55e7a7449f770e46330161cb7bd525c4417a:1135
SockJS</SockJS.prototype._didMessage@http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?502d55e7a7449f770e46330161cb7bd525c4417a:1193
SockJS</SockJS.websocket/that.ws.onmessage@http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?502d55e7a7449f770e46330161cb7bd525c4417a:1340
"
```

Comment: Can we see your router code? In `Router.go('home')`, the `home` should be the name of the route, not the name of the template.

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't realise that you weren't using Iron-Router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Router.go(routeName)` is the correct function in [Iron-Router](https://atmospherejs.com/package/iron-router), but you are using [Router](https://atmospherejs.com/package/router). The correct function in this package is `Meteor.Router.to('/');`

Comment: I am using to follow as you told but also came error :`Exception in defer callback: ("/",[object Object])@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron-router.js?e9fac8016598ea034d4f30de5f0d356a9a24b6c5:1668
("/",[object Object])@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron-router.js?e9fac8016598ea034d4f30de5f0d356a9a24b6c5:1185`.So please suggest me what to do?.@user3374348

Comment: You should probably switch to Iroun-Router, as Router is deprecated according to Hubert OG, and I don't know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The old `router` package was deprecated long time ago and Meteor's client code has changed dramatically since then. If you use the old router now, you will get errors.

The correct solution is to replace the `router` package with the current standard, `iron-router`. Then you can use `Router.go('main')`. See [Iron Router's Github page](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) for documentation.

Comment: Can you please conform once again to pass path or template name in Router.go('Path or Tempalte Name ')?.@Hubert OG

Comment: You pass the path name, the one you have defined in the route map.